# how to get list of group members for group name

Tags: sql, oracle

I have `GROUPs` and `USERs`.  `GROUPs` can contain `USERs` and other `GROUPs`.

The data is stored in one table, `NODES` like below, where the `PARENT_NDE_ID` is the group/user's containing parent.  A user always has a parent that is a group's id.  If the group has no parent then the parent id and group id are equal.

```
NODES
-----
NDE_ID (int)
PARENT_NDE_ID (int)
DESCRIPTION (string, any name)
NDE_TYPE (string, either 'USER' or 'GROUP')
```

My question is, I want to get a list of members in for a group.

I want to produce either:

```
GROUP NAME | MEMBER NAME
---
Group A | Group B
Group A | Bob
Group B | Dave
Group C | Mike
```

Or, a build query that accepts a group name and gives me a list of members which I can run manually for each group name, something like:

```
select NODES.DESCRIPTION, NODES.NDE_TYPE 
where PARENT_NDE_ID = (the id associated with the provided group name string)
```

Any help is greatly apprecaited!

Comment: What platform/sql dielect are you on? Or must it be independent? (In case of Sql Server, the tag to look for would be 'recursive Common Table Expressions', on first glance)

Comment: @KekuSemau It's an Oracle db.  Hope this helps!  I'm not much of a SQL guy, outside of the very basic select, insert, update statements.

Comment: This is a complicated SQL statement.  It requires recursively determining group membership.  In Oracle, you do this with the `CONNECT BY` keyword.  However, I do not use it enough to just write the SQL.

Comment: What's up with the abbreviation of `NODE`?

Answer (score 0):

You need CONNECT BY - read this URL: [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm)